# How to extend Vue.prototype reactively

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to write a simple plugin. It's a directive to add ripple effect to any element. So far the custom directive works fine (check [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/yerkopalma/tzw9ho3k/4/)), but I want to add some data to the Vue instance so the user can modify some values globally. I wan it to be used like this.

```
new Vue({
  ripple: {
    color: '#f18c16'
  }
})
```

and that would modify the color of all ripple directives in this instance. As far as I know this isn't documented, so I inspect a litle in some Vue plugin and I came to this code.

```
const ripple = {
    color: '#000'
}
const init = Vue.prototype._init

Vue.prototype._init = function(options) {
    options = options || {}
    Vue.util.defineReactive(this, '$ripple', ripple)
  init.call(this, options)
}
```

And in my directive I use it like this

```
  if (this.modifiers.white) {
    point.style['background-color'] = '#fff'
  } else {
    point.style['background-color'] = this.vm.$ripple.color
  }
```

But that only adds the `$ripple` property to my Vue instance and the declaration that I expected isn't working. Check [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/yerkopalma/tzw9ho3k/5/). So, my question is how can I use the `ripple` option defined for my directive? Is there any official/standard way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to define reactivity.

Simply use this:

```
this.vm.$options.ripple.color
```

instead of this:

```
this.vm.$ripple.color
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pespantelis/tzw9ho3k/6/